# Pass data from view to controller in asp.net mvc4 razor

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've situation like, I've got two different views and one common controller (and its method too) for both. One is create item view and another is edit item view. My controller has one method called details. Now I want to inform controller that I'm coming form create or edit. On this basis my whole code will execute.

**csHTML**

```
<a href="..\example\details" id="iCreate">Create</a>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#iCreate').click(function(){ 
    @Session["createMode"] = true; // Not working...
    @ViewBag["createMode"] = true; // Not working...
 });
});
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult details()
{
    // How to get data here??? 
     if(createMode){
      }
      else{
      }
}
```

To achieve this one way is pass parameter in `querystring`, but I don't want to do that.
So is there any other way to pass data from View to Controller??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

regarding

```
@Session["createMode"] = true; // Not working...
@ViewBag["createMode"] = true; // Not working...
```

This cannot work because @Session and @ViewBag are server side variables which cannot be changed via JavaScript (which is client side) obviously.

You can use

1. Query string (which you mentioned)
2. Post form data
3. Use Ajax request and write a controller action which retrieves your request

to achieve what you want

Comment: Nice explanation. I'll look for another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this

in HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="createMode" value="False" />
```

javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#iCreate').click(function(){ 
    $('#createMode').val('True');
 });
});
```

Controller:

```
public void details(bool createMode)
{
    //createMode will automatically be passed
     if(createMode){
      }
      else{
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but can you give some more clarification that how value of `bool createMode` will pass on click of link?? You've just changed the hidden input type's value.

Comment: every input will be passed to the controller,  the value of "True" will be the value , c# will easily convert the string "True" into a bool at the controller, and it will work just like you wanted

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is by using Ajax

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#iCreate').click(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("details")' + '?mode=create'
    }).done(function(){
      //do something
    });
 });

public void details(string mode)
{
     if(mode.Equals("create")){
      }
      else{
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but I've one question that at controller side I've `ActionResult` method not `void`. Sorry for the bloof.

Comment: It should work the same, whether the method is void or an action method. I actually made a small mistake. Url.Action will only work if the method is an ActionResult. So the above code should work fine by changing void to ActionResult.